# RangeError: invalid array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to get an array out of the keys on my object but the length should 0 when the Object is empty. The length of array is correct when I try `console.log()` with the array but my code stucks throwing the following error on my browser and it stops the execution:

```
RangeError: invalid array length
burger/transformedIngredients<
src/components/Burger/Burger.js:8

   5 | const burger = (props) => {
   6 |   let transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map(igKey => (
   7 |     // eslint-disable-next-line max-len,react/no-array-index-key
>  8 |     [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />)
   9 |   )).reduce((arr, el) => (
  10 |     arr.concat(el)
  11 |   ), []);
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
const burger = (props) => {
  let transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map(igKey => (
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len,react/no-array-index-key
    [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />)
  )).reduce((arr, el) => (
    arr.concat(el)
  ), []);

  if (transformedIngredients.length === 0) {
    transformedIngredients = <p>Please add some ingredients!</p>;
  }
```

I am passing `ingredients` from here:

```
class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    ingredients: {
      salad: 0,
      bacon: 0,
      cheese: 0,
      meat: 0,
    },
    totalPrice: 4,
  };
render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Burger ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
        <BuildControls
          ingredientAdded={this.addIngredientHandler}
          ingredientRemoved={this.removeIngredientHandler}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why are you doing an extra mapping of the keys and creating a multidimensional array, but you can change your code to this if you want to render an ingredient for each key:

```
const burger = (props) => {
  let transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map((igKey, i) => (
    <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />
  ));
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm new to React and I was following a course. After copying your code the error was gone but my browser throwed another error:
`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`
Any solution to this?

Comment: Are you calling `setState` somewhere inside your render methods?

Comment: No, I'm not. You can check my full code [here](https://github.com/ceerees12/burger-builder)

Comment: See [this](https://imgur.com/Tnyioia) and [this](https://imgur.com/wWwuVOV)

Comment: From the screenshots it seems like the error comes from `ingredientHandler` method, but I can't find it in your code.

Comment: Sorry, there was some problem with git. You can check the repo now and find the updated code

Comment: @shirish well yeah, on line 19 in buildControls you do `added={props.ingredientAdded(ctrl.type)}` which calls the `ingredientAdded` all the time. You need to change it to ` added={() => props.ingredientAdded(ctrl.type)}`. By the way, you should start your React components names with uppercase.

Comment: I did it for `removed={props.ingredientRemoved(ctrl.type)}` too and it worked. But I still don't understand what was the error, can you explain it more or guide me to some docs?

Comment: Basically `props.ingredientRemoved(ctrl.type)` executes straight away and causes rerender which causes it to execute again and cause re-render and so on. Wrapping it in a function will prevent that since altho it will be called straight away, it will return another function to be called later.

Comment: removed={props.ingredientRemoved(ctrl.type)} this is wrong if your passing parameter like in this case (ctrl.type) you have to use () eg: removed={() =>props.ingredientRemoved(ctrl.type)}

Answer (score 3):

The error may happen if one of ingredients has a negative value, for example:

```
state = {
  ingredients: {
    salad: -1, // this will cause the error
    bacon: 0,
    cheese: 0,
    meat: 0,
  },
  totalPrice: 4,
};
```

You can prevent this situation by ensuring that negative number will not be passed in the `Array` constructor, for example you can pass `0` if the number is negative:

```
[...Array(Math.max(0, props.ingredients[igKey]))]
```

Comment: None of my ingredient will have negative value. There error that the question was about is solved but I'm getting another error now(check the comments in first answer)

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking the same course and got the same error. Check your reducer.js file and compare it to source code provided in the course. In my case, the array passed from reducer.js didn't match the array received by Burger.js. The error was gone after fixing the reducer.js file.

My code looks like this after the fix:

```
    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: {
          ...state.ingredients,
          [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1
        },
        totalPrice: state.totalPrice + INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]
      };
    case actionTypes.REMOVE_INGREDIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients: {
          ...state.ingredients,
          [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] - 1
        },
        totalPrice: state.totalPrice + INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]
      };
    default:
      return state;
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

I am learning react from same course and i had same issue that you have. In your const INGREDIENT_PRICES all object should be same case as you are using in buildcontrols.js and in this const controls check uppper and lower cause of words match with INGREDIENT_PRICES then issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

in this case i narrowed down my error to when trying to pass the price value to the query params by setting Number.parseFloat and toFixed on the price integer, thus eliminating the error causing stringified decimal.

```
purchaseContinueHandler = () => {            
            const queryParams = [];
            let price = Number.parseFloat(this.state.totalPrice).toFixed(2);

            for (let i in this.state.ingredients) {
                queryParams.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.state.ingredients[i]));
            }
            queryParams.push('price=' + price);

            const queryString = queryParams.join('&'); 

            this.props.history.push({
                pathname: '/checkout',
                search: '?' + queryString
            });
```

the error was caused for me by having a string decimal in the price value.

Answer (score 1):

I was following the same course and faced same issue. Included `totalPrice` as key value pair in ingredients object(in reducer.js file) which is not the case as it is separate key value pair in updated state for each action.

Before fix-

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions';

const initialState = {
    ingredients: {
        salad: 0,
        bacon: 0,
        cheese: 0,
        meat: 0
    },
    totalPrice: 4,
};

const INGREDIENT_PRICES = {
    salad: 0.5,
    bacon: 1.3,
    cheese: 0.6,
    meat: 1,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT: return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: {
                ...state.ingredients,
                [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1,
                `totalPrice: state.totalPrice + INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]`
            }
        };

        case actionTypes.REMOVE_INGREDIENT: return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: {
                ...state.ingredients,
                [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] - 1,
                `totalPrice: state.totalPrice - INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]`
            }
        }

        default : return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

After fix-

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions';

const initialState = {
    ingredients: {
        salad: 0,
        bacon: 0,
        cheese: 0,
        meat: 0
    },
    totalPrice: 4,
};

const INGREDIENT_PRICES = {
    salad: 0.5,
    bacon: 1.3,
    cheese: 0.6,
    meat: 1,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT: return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: {
                ...state.ingredients,
                [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] + 1,
            },
            `totalPrice: state.totalPrice + INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]`
        };

        case actionTypes.REMOVE_INGREDIENT: return {
            ...state,
            ingredients: {
                ...state.ingredients,
                [action.ingredientName]: state.ingredients[action.ingredientName] - 1,
            },
            `totalPrice: state.totalPrice - INGREDIENT_PRICES[action.ingredientName]`
        }

        default : return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const queryParams = [];
        for(let i in this.state.ingredients){
            queryParams.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.state.ingredients[i]));
            }
    const queryString = queryParams.join('&'); // '&' can cause errors if left out of the queryString 
        this.props.history.push({
             pathname: '/checkout',
             search:'?' + queryString
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Has the same error as yours, possible error was in the adding of ingredients.

Solved mine by changing "[]" to "{}"  in the line of copying object. I did not noticed that I used the [].

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake too, changing 'b' and 'c' to uppercase 
in "bacon" and "cheese".

By making every character in the same case the issue is resolved:

```
const controls=[
  {label:'salad',type:'salad'},
  {label:'bacon',type:'bacon'},
  {label:'cheese',type:'cheese'},
  {label:'meat',type:'meat'}
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same course please check the ingredient name you are using in your database those should be same as in the `BuildControls.js`, ingredients type should be same as you write in your database. This will definitely solve your problem.

This error occurs because of the selection of wrong name that's why it says Invalid array length.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you that have taken the time to provide your answer and thoughts.
I had the same issue and the solution was just to change the key value to lowercase,

For example on the code below:
The mistake was having `'Price'` Uppercased instead of `'price'` lowercased

```js
checkoutContinuedHandler = () => {
        const queryParams = [];
        for (let ing in this.state.ingredients) {
            queryParams.push(encodeURIComponent(ing) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.state.ingredients[ing]));
        }
        queryParams.push('price=' + this.state.totalPrice.toFixed(2));
        const queryString = queryParams.join('&');
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: '/checkout',
            search: '?' + queryString
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the spread Operator from ...state.ingredients and it will Work!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is perfectly fine.
This error occurs in the way you implement your reducer.
But I will still assume you are getting it from new URLSearchParams();
If that is the case, then check how you are pushing or rather passing your ingredients to the url.
For instance:

```
    const queryParams = [];
        for(let i in this.state.ingredients){
            queryParams.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.state.ingredients[i]));
            }
    const queryString = queryParams.join('&'); // '&' can cause errors if left out of the queryString resulting to RangeError
        this.props.history.push({
             pathname: '/checkout',
             search:'?' + queryString
    });
```

Thus, check how you join them in the string or how you are passing them to the burger component. This error is not in the burger component you are pointing out, rather from the source of the ingredients; especially if you are passing them to the url. try printing the:

```
console.log(this.props.location.search);
```

if you see an error, like size: 1, then check how you joined the string.